# Perl Regex URL contains string but not similar string

Tags: regex, perl

I need to write regex for Perl so that it matches `/contact` (and everything beyond so /contact/talk etc.).

But I also have URL for `/contacts` so I want it to skip this.

So far I've only been able to write code either for exact matches or for

So something along the lines of:

```
if ($uri =~ m/contact/i ) {
   ## Redirect somewhere
}
```

This also redirects everything within `/contacts` though which is where I'm struggling.

Comment: The URI is suppose to be case sensitive (at least the path part), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($uri =~ m!/contact(?:/|$)!) {
  #
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($uri =~ m/\/contact(?:$|\/)/i ) {
  ## Redirect somewhere
}
```

Will match `/contact` because of the `$`, and everything like `/contact/...`

Answer (score 0):

`\b` is a word boundary marker, which prevents this match from being in the middle of a word:

```
if ($uri =~ m|\bcontact\b|i ) {
   ## Redirect somewhere
}
```

I would add it to the beginning and end, so you don't match `foocontact` either. Or you could make sure that a slash precedes contact.

```
if ($uri =~ m|/contact\b|i ) {
   ## Redirect somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo -e "/contacts/qqq\n/contact\n/contact/talk\n/ConTact\n/contactx/"|
perl -ne 'm{/contact(?:/|$)} and print'
```

Output:

```
/contact
/contact/talk
```

Comment: Yeah.. I kinda posted that 5min ago :/

Comment: @Loamhoof: :) Sorry, it took time to check the results... I don't think there is too much variance to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\/contact\//
```

there is some guesswork involved - it appears that your urls start with `/contact`, in case they don't, drop the initial caret.